# e approximations

Tags: number-representation

Can you help me? I'm writing program to calculate e with given percision (not using function from Mathematics) by using e=sum (1/k!) k=0 to infinity. I have this:

```
c=Input["Input the precision"]
s=Sum[1/k!,{k,0,infinity}];
If[Abs[N[E]-N[s]<c,Print[N[s]],k++]
```

And it is not ok,but I'm not sure what exactly is not correct.

Comment: First, not infinity, but `Infinity` - upper-case. Second, the third line makes no sense, the `Abs` isn't closed, your `s` is exactly `E` so `N[E]-N[s]` is exactly zero, `k` is an index of summation, so I guess you intended to do `n++` with`s=Sum[1/k!,{k,0,n}]`... // I'd do `s[n_] := Sum[1/k!, {k, 0, n}]; k = 0;
While[Abs[N[E] - N[s[k]]] > c, k++]; 
k`.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @corey979, doesn't work.

Comment: The suggestion by @corey979 It does work if you specify `c`, and  evaluate `s[k]` after the loop completes. You don't need `Input` and `Print`. You should probably also look up `While` in the documentation.

Comment: I have this and if I input precision 0,0000001 the answer is still 2.71828                                                                                                     c = Input["Input the precision"]; 
s[a_] := Sum[1/k!, {k, 0, a}]; k = 0; While[Abs[N[E] - N[s[k]]] > c, 
 k++]; N[s[k]]

Comment: Done, Thank you :)                                                                                                                c = Input["Input the precision"]; 
s[a_] := Sum[1/k!, {k, 0, a}]; k = 0; While[Abs[N[E] - N[s[k]]] > c, 
 k++]; N[s[k], k - 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fun, and as a puzzle to figure out:

```
step[{k_, sum_, error_}] := {k + 1, sum + error*k/(k + 1), error*k/(k + 1)^2};

res = NestWhileList[step, {1, 1 + 1, 1}, Last[#] >= 1.*^-6 &];

TableForm[Transpose@{res[[All, 1]], N@res[[All, 3]], N[E - res[[All, 2]]]},
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"k", "error (est)", "error (actual)"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can find the approximation with error less than `10^-6` like this:

```
N@res[[-1, 2]]
(*  2.71828  *)
```